# How to Read almost 200 columns from excel file using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to import an excel-sheet which have almost 210 columns with laravel code,
my code is working fine for less columns for eg. 50 columns but its not responding while i try to import the file which have 125 or more columns.

I have increase the maximum execution time by using ini_set('max_execution_time', 240); but still not able to run my code propely
I am using laravel 5.2 
Here is my code

```
$path = $request->file('excel_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
                $reader->ignoreEmpty();
                $reader->formatDates(true);
            })->get()->toArray();
            $data = array_filter($data);
            $excel_header = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path)->get()->getHeading();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($excel_header);
            exit;
```

Comment: If the code is running through a webserver and not over cli (which has unlimited execution time as default), you also need to increase the execution times there, too.